# Why does this whole term go away with the $dx$?

Tags: indefinite-integrals, differential

I'm learning how to take indefinite integrals with U-substitutions on [khanacademy.org](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/calculus/integral-calculus/u_substitution/v/u-substitution), and in one of the videos he says that: $$\int e^{x^3+x^2}(3x^2+2x) \, dx = e^{x^3+x^2} + \text{constant}$$
I understand that the differential goes away, but not how the whole $(3x^2+2x)$ term go away together with the $dx$.

Comment: $d(x^3 + x^2) = (3x^2 + 2x)dx$.

Comment: Presumably you've seen the steps of integration that lead to the RHS. Can you typed them here and pinpoint what exactly you're having trouble with? Anyway, if you differentiate the RHS, what do you get?

Comment: Your equation just says that $e^{x^3 + x^2} + C$ is an anti-derivative of $e^{x^3 + x^2}(3x^2 + 2x)$.  You can check that this is true using the chain rule.

Comment: @littleO Yes, I see that now, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $u$ substitution here is $u = x^3 + x^2$. Then $du = (3x^2 + 2x) \, dx$. This allows us to rewrite

$$\int e^{x^3 + x^2}(3x^2 + 2x) \, dx = \int e^u \, du$$

At which point we integrate and substitute back. You can see that you cannot do a $u$-substitution without accounting for the change from $dx$ to $du$, and it is this that takes care of the $(3x^2 + 2x)$.

Comment: I was surprised to read an answer that doesn't mention the term "chain rule".  That's what this is.

Comment: So the $(3x^2+2x)$ and the $dx$ just disappears into the $du$ which later disappears when we take the integral of $e^u$?

Answer (score 1):

Using a substitution, you have

$$u=x^3+x^2,du=(3x^2+2x)dx$$

The $du$ value is the derivative of the $u$ value with respect to $x$.  As part of the substitution, the $dx$ value must be changed to support integration over the substituted variable.  So we have the following:

$$\int e^{x^3+x^2}(3x^2+2x)dx=\int e^udu$$

which easily evaluates to

$$e^u+C=e^{x^3+x^2}+C$$

So the $(3x^2+2x)dx$ portion is simply being replaced by $du$ as that is the value it has.